# Is it possible to set per-mode for math and displaymath environment separately in siunitx?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

I would like to globally define the `per-mode` of `siunitx` for math environment and displaymath environment separately. Is this somehow possible?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}
This is an inline equation: $a = \SI{10}{\meter\per\second\squared}$, to show inline behaviour.

And this is the same equation in displaymath environment:
\begin{equation*}
a = \SI{10}{\meter\per\second\squared}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image]

What I would love to do is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode-math=symbol,
         per-mode-displaymath=fraction}

\begin{document}
This is an inline equation: $a = \SI{10}{\meter\per\second\squared}$, to show inline behaviour.

And this is the same equation in displaymath environment:
\begin{equation*}
a = \SI{10}{\meter\per\second\squared}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Which then should produce the following output:
[image]

Comment: Did you see `per-mode = symbol-or-fraction` in the manual?

Comment: @JosephWright: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Joseph Wright pointed out: The solution here is to use `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol-or-fraction}` as described in the `siunitx` manual:

> Finally, it is possible for the behaviour of the `\per` function to
>   depend on the prevailing math style. Setting per-mode to
>   symbol-or-fraction will use the symbol setting for in line math, and
>   the fraction setting when used in `\displaystyle` math.

So for a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol-or-fraction}

\begin{document}
This is an inline equation: $a = \SI{10}{\meter\per\second\squared}$, to show inline behaviour.

And this is the same equation in displaymath environment:
\begin{equation*}
a = \SI{10}{\meter\per\second\squared}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Which works as expected:
[image]